# XSLT issue PART 2

Tags: xml, xslt

I got a solution for a previous issue, now the new question is:
If I Have following set of requests:

```
<notification>
    <transaction id="B0GQ95PH07QR"/>
    <info origin="INT.02" type="NPM Event" hostname="prmrte02" time="2015-02-28T02:26:42+02:00"/>
    <data>
        <admin originator="" event_time="2015-02-28T02:26:42+02:00">
            <input>
                <request_set tx_id="Y2xfMDFfMDE6LWFjODQ2MTQ6Y2E3Mjo1NGVmYjA3NjoxNTE3ODA=#YWM4NDYxNDpjYTcyOjU0ZWZiMDc2OjE1MTc5Ng==" tx_timeout="2015-02-28T00:36:51.824Z" tx_command="start">
                    <transaction id="B0GQ95PH07QR"/>
                    <request report="">
                        <update>
                            <account_data id="2005637" parent="3615732" Status="5" instance="1">
                                <info>
                                    <additional languageid="ARA" nwop="WMP" expdat="2015-08-17T00:00:00+02:00" exptyp="Deactivate" status="5" as="PAS/SUSP" dyn="ch=US,gn=,ct=1,enc=true,tp=TP_STUDENTS"/>
                                </info>
                                <event_map>
                                    <item id="101" value="ARA"/>
                                    <item id="102" value="WMP"/>
                                    <item id="110" value="2015-08-17T00:00:00.000+02:00"/>
                                    <item id="111" value="Deactivate"/>
                                </event_map>
                                <map>
                                    <item id="3" name="TOKEN" value="1234567" vfrom="2014-10-28T21:51:36+02:00"/>
                                    <item id="2" name="MSISDN" value="1234567" vfrom="2014-10-28T21:51:36+02:00"/>
                                    <item id="1" name="IMSI" value="425062260312424" vfrom="2014-10-28T21:51:36+02:00"/>
                                </map>
                                <balances>
                                    <item id="40" name="BLC_Points_Limit" value="0.0" rollover_cnt="0"/>
                                    <item id="50" name="BLP_Bonus_GeoPoll" value="0.0" rollover_cnt="0"/>
                                    <item id="3" name="BLP_Bonus" value="0.0" rollover_cnt="0"/>
                                    <item id="38" name="BLC_Transfered_Points" value="0.0" rollover_cnt="0"/>
                                    <item id="39" name="BLC_TP" value="0.0" rollover_cnt="0"/>
                                    <item id="22" name="BLC_Points" value="0.0" rollover_cnt="0"/>
                                    <item id="62" name="BLB_PSR_Flag" value="0.0" rollover_cnt="0"/>
                                    <item id="43" name="BLP_Bonus_Points" value="0.0" rollover_cnt="0"/>
                                    <item id="1" name="BLP_Main" value="0.0" rollover_cnt="0"/>
                                    <item id="32" name="BLC_SEC_OFFNET_MTC" value="0.0" rollover_cnt="0"/>
                                    <item id="34" name="BLC_CT_USAGE" value="0.0" rollover_cnt="0"/>
                                    <item id="2" name="BLP_Debt" value="0.0" rollover_cnt="0"/>
                                    <item id="53" name="BLP_Act_Gift" value="0.0" rollover_cnt="0"/>
                                </balances>
                                <recurring>
                                    <item id="38" index="1" spc_id="30957767" bundle_id="61" start_date="2015-02-19T20:45:34+02:00"/>
                                </recurring>
                                <service_options>
                                    <item id="1" bundle_id="1" state="1" spc_id="25284120"/>
                                    <item id="1209" usdate="2014-10-28T21:51:36+02:00" bundle_id="1" state="0" spc_id="25284259"/>
                                    <item id="1192" usdate="2014-10-28T21:51:36+02:00" bundle_id="1" state="0" spc_id="25284225"/>
                                    <item id="1296" usdate="2014-10-28T21:51:36+02:00" bundle_id="65" state="0" spc_id="25284378"/>
                                    <item id="1198" usdate="2014-10-28T21:51:36+02:00" bundle_id="1" state="0" spc_id="25284136"/>
                                    <item id="1020" usdate="2014-10-28T21:51:36+02:00" bundle_id="56" state="0" spc_id="25284301"/>
                                    <item id="1201" usdate="2014-10-28T21:51:36+02:00" bundle_id="1" state="0" spc_id="25284233"/>
                                    <item id="1179" usdate="2014-10-28T21:51:36+02:00" bundle_id="60" state="0" spc_id="25284088"/>
                                    <item id="1174" usdate="2014-10-28T21:51:36+02:00" bundle_id="60" state="0" spc_id="25284099"/>
                                    <item id="1193" usdate="2014-10-28T21:51:36+02:00" bundle_id="1" state="0" spc_id="25284167"/>
                                    <item id="1202" usdate="2014-10-28T21:51:36+02:00" bundle_id="1" state="0" spc_id="25284271"/>
                                    <item id="1328" usdate="2015-02-27T21:49:35+02:00" bundle_id="74" state="0" spc_id="31047013"/>
                                    <item id="1295" usdate="2015-02-17T11:13:04+02:00" bundle_id="60" state="0" spc_id="30914089"/>
                                    <item id="1190" usdate="2014-10-28T21:51:36+02:00" bundle_id="1" state="0" spc_id="25284195"/>
                                    <item id="1194" usdate="2014-10-28T21:51:36+02:00" bundle_id="1" state="0" spc_id="25284155"/>
                                    <item id="1292" usdate="2014-10-28T21:51:36+02:00" bundle_id="65" state="0" spc_id="25284363"/>
                                    <item id="1207" usdate="2014-10-28T21:51:36+02:00" bundle_id="65" state="0" spc_id="25284336"/>
                                    <item id="1210" usdate="2014-10-28T21:51:36+02:00" bundle_id="65" state="0" spc_id="25284350"/>
                                    <item id="1200" usdate="2014-10-28T21:51:36+02:00" bundle_id="1" state="0" spc_id="25284248"/>
                                    <item id="1197" usdate="2014-10-28T21:51:36+02:00" bundle_id="1" state="0" spc_id="25284181"/>
                                    <item id="1307" usdate="2014-10-28T21:51:36+02:00" bundle_id="60" state="0" spc_id="25284076"/>
                                    <item id="1195" usdate="2014-10-28T21:51:36+02:00" bundle_id="1" state="0" spc_id="25284208"/>
                                    <item id="1284" usdate="2015-02-19T20:45:34+02:00" bundle_id="61" state="0"/>
                                </service_options>
                                <ps_options>
                                    <item id="6" name="PO_FF_ONNET_10IN1">
                                        <match value="1" vfrom="2015-02-19T20:45:35+02:00">0769723924</match>
                                    </item>
                                </ps_options>
                                <thresholds accountId="2005637" seqno="13">
                                    <item name="TH_BLC_Points_Allow_Redeem" id="502" class="BAS" new_level="HIGH,LOW" nlid="2,1"/>
                                    <item name="TH_LI_BLP_Main" id="501" class="EXTERNAL" new_level="HIGH,LOW" nlid="2,1"/>
                                    <item name="Threshold_PreCallAnnouncements" id="510" class="EXTERNAL" new_level="HIGH,LOW" nlid="3,2"/>
                                    <item name="THR_BLB_SMS_ONNET" id="509" class="EXTERNAL" new_level="HIGH" nlid="3"/>
                                    <item name="THR_BLB_MMS_ONNET" id="505" class="EXTERNAL" new_level="HIGH" nlid="3"/>
                                    <item name="THR_BLB_GPRS" id="503" class="EXTERNAL" new_level="HIGH,LOW,ZERO" nlid="3,2,1"/>
                                </thresholds>
                            </account_data>
                        </update>
                    </request>
                    <request report="">
                        <update>
                            <account_data id="3615734" parent="3615732" Status="5" instance="1">
                                <info>
                                    <additional languageid="ARA" nwop="WMP" status="5" as="PAS/SUSP" dyn="ch=US,gn=,ct=1,enc=true,tp=TP_SHABABE"/>
                                </info>
                                <event_map>
                                    <item id="101" value="ARA"/>
                                    <item id="102" value="WMP"/>
                                </event_map>
                                <map>
                                    <item id="1" name="IMSI" value="425062250251886" vfrom="2014-04-01T14:49:46+02:00"/>
                                    <item id="3" name="TOKEN" value="768681826" vfrom="2014-04-01T14:49:46+02:00"/>
                                    <item id="2" name="MSISDN" value="768681826" vfrom="2014-04-01T14:49:46+02:00"/>
                                </map>
                                <balances>
                                    <item id="39" name="BLC_TP" value="0.0" rollover_cnt="0"/>
                                    <item id="1" name="BLP_Main" value="0.0" rollover_cnt="0"/>
                                    <item id="43" name="BLP_Bonus_Points" value="0.0" rollover_cnt="0"/>
                                    <item id="2" name="BLP_Debt" value="0.0" rollover_cnt="0"/>
                                    <item id="40" name="BLC_Points_Limit" value="0.0" rollover_cnt="0"/>
                                    <item id="3" name="BLP_Bonus" value="0.0" rollover_cnt="0"/>
                                    <item id="50" name="BLP_Bonus_GeoPoll" value="0.0" rollover_cnt="0"/>
                                    <item id="38" name="BLC_Transfered_Points" value="0.0" rollover_cnt="0"/>
                                    <item id="22" name="BLC_Points" value="0.0" rollover_cnt="0"/>
                                    <item id="62" name="BLB_PSR_Flag" value="0.0" rollover_cnt="0"/>
                                    <item id="32" name="BLC_SEC_OFFNET_MTC" value="0.0" rollover_cnt="0"/>
                                    <item id="83" name="BLC_FF_Shababe_CAP_Period" value="0.0" rollover_cnt="0"/>
                                    <item id="53" name="BLP_Act_Gift" value="0.0" rollover_cnt="0"/>
                                </balances>
                                <service_options>
                                    <item id="1" bundle_id="1" state="0" spc_id="28054950"/>
                                    <item id="1292" usdate="2014-04-23T12:49:14+02:00" uedate="2015-02-02T05:33:05+02:00" bundle_id="65" state="0" spc_id="28055113"/>
                                    <item id="1194" usdate="2014-04-01T14:49:46+02:00" uedate="2015-02-02T05:33:05+02:00" bundle_id="1" state="0" spc_id="28055028"/>
                                    <item id="1193" usdate="2014-04-01T14:49:46+02:00" uedate="2015-02-02T05:33:05+02:00" bundle_id="1" state="0" spc_id="28055051"/>
                                    <item id="1179" usdate="2014-04-01T14:49:46+02:00" uedate="2015-02-02T05:33:05+02:00" bundle_id="60" state="0" spc_id="28054905"/>
                                    <item id="1202" usdate="2014-04-01T14:49:46+02:00" uedate="2015-02-02T05:33:05+02:00" bundle_id="1" state="0" spc_id="28055046"/>
                                    <item id="1209" usdate="2014-04-01T14:49:46+02:00" uedate="2015-02-02T05:33:05+02:00" bundle_id="1" state="0" spc_id="28055038"/>
                                    <item id="1200" usdate="2014-04-01T14:49:46+02:00" uedate="2015-02-02T05:33:05+02:00" bundle_id="1" state="0" spc_id="28055004"/>
                                    <item id="1210" usdate="2014-04-23T12:49:14+02:00" uedate="2015-02-02T05:33:05+02:00" bundle_id="65" state="0" spc_id="28055104"/>
                                    <item id="1208" usdate="2014-04-01T14:49:46+02:00" uedate="2015-02-02T05:33:05+02:00" bundle_id="66" state="0" spc_id="28054733"/>
                                    <item id="1190" usdate="2014-04-01T14:49:46+02:00" uedate="2015-02-02T05:33:05+02:00" bundle_id="1" state="0" spc_id="28055075"/>
                                    <item id="1195" usdate="2014-04-01T14:49:46+02:00" uedate="2015-02-02T05:33:05+02:00" bundle_id="1" state="0" spc_id="28055033"/>
                                    <item id="1174" usdate="2014-04-01T14:49:46+02:00" uedate="2015-02-02T05:33:05+02:00" bundle_id="60" state="0" spc_id="28054894"/>
                                    <item id="1197" usdate="2014-04-01T14:49:46+02:00" uedate="2015-02-02T05:33:05+02:00" bundle_id="1" state="0" spc_id="28055068"/>
                                    <item id="1201" usdate="2014-04-01T14:49:46+02:00" uedate="2015-02-02T05:33:05+02:00" bundle_id="1" state="0" spc_id="28055013"/>
                                    <item id="1207" usdate="2014-04-23T12:49:14+02:00" uedate="2015-02-02T05:33:05+02:00" bundle_id="65" state="0" spc_id="28055097"/>
                                    <item id="1168" usdate="2014-11-26T14:40:31+02:00" uedate="2015-02-02T05:33:05+02:00" bundle_id="59" state="0" spc_id="28054856"/>
                                    <item id="1296" usdate="2014-04-23T12:49:14+02:00" uedate="2015-02-02T05:33:05+02:00" bundle_id="65" state="0" spc_id="28055122"/>
                                    <item id="1307" usdate="2014-04-23T12:49:14+02:00" uedate="2015-02-02T05:33:05+02:00" bundle_id="60" state="0" spc_id="28054886"/>
                                    <item id="1198" usdate="2014-04-01T14:49:46+02:00" uedate="2015-02-02T05:33:05+02:00" bundle_id="1" state="0" spc_id="28054991"/>
                                    <item id="1169" usdate="2014-11-04T05:33:04+02:00" uedate="2015-02-02T05:33:05+02:00" bundle_id="59" state="0" spc_id="28054849"/>
                                    <item id="1192" usdate="2014-04-01T14:49:46+02:00" uedate="2015-02-02T05:33:05+02:00" bundle_id="1" state="0" spc_id="28055059"/>
                                </service_options>
                                <ps_options>
                                    <item id="6" name="PO_FF_ONNET_10IN1">
                                        <match value="1">0769723924</match>
                                    </item>
                                </ps_options>
                                <thresholds accountId="3615734" seqno="2">
                                    <item name="TH_LI_BLP_Main" id="501" class="EXTERNAL" new_level="HIGH,LOW" nlid="2,1"/>
                                    <item name="Threshold_PreCallAnnouncements" id="510" class="EXTERNAL" new_level="HIGH,LOW" nlid="3,2"/>
                                    <item name="TH_BLC_Points_Allow_Redeem" id="502" class="BAS" new_level="HIGH,LOW" nlid="2,1"/>
                                </thresholds>
                            </account_data>
                        </update>
                    </request>
                </request_set>
            </input>
            <output>
                <response_set code="0">
                    <transaction id="B0GQ95PH07QR"/>
                    <text>Ok</text>
                    <response code="0">
                        <text>Ok</text>
                        <update>
                            <account_data id="2005637" parent="3615732" Status="2">
                                <thresholds seqno="12"/>
                                <map>
                                    <item id="1" value="425062260312424"/>
                                    <item id="2" value="769874479"/>
                                </map>
                            </account_data>
                        </update>
                    </response>
                    <response code="0">
                        <text>Ok</text>
                        <update>
                            <account_data id="3615734" parent="3615732" Status="5">
                                <thresholds seqno="1"/>
                                <map>
                                    <item id="1" value="425062250251886"/>
                                    <item id="2" value="768681826"/>
                                </map>
                            </account_data>
                        </update>
                    </response>
                </response_set>
            </output>
        </admin>
    </data>
</notification>
```

The current XSLT applied to this input file will catch for following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
        <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
        <xsl:template match="/">
                <xsl:variable name="UID">
                        <xsl:value-of select="ND-OFM-04"/>
                </xsl:variable>

                <xsl:variable name="LANG">
                        <xsl:value-of select="/notification/data/admin/input/request_set/request/update/account_data/info/additional/@languageid"/>
                </xsl:variable>

                <xsl:variable name="IMSI">
                        <xsl:value-of select="/notification/data/admin/input/request_set/request/update/account_data/map/item[@id = 1 and not(@vto)]/@value"/>
                </xsl:variable>

                <xsl:variable name="MSISDN">
                        <xsl:value-of select="/notification/data/admin/input/request_set/request/update/account_data/map/item[@id = 2 and not(@vto)]/@value"/>
                </xsl:variable>

                <xsl:variable name="NOTIFID">
                        <xsl:value-of select="/notification/transaction/@id"/>
                </xsl:variable>

                <xsl:variable name="ACID">
                        <xsl:value-of select="/notification/data/admin/input/request_set/request/update/account_data[@Status='5']/@id"/>
                </xsl:variable>

                <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:gol="http://www.example.org/ws/GOldEventTransaction">
                        <soapenv:Header/>
                        <soapenv:Body>
                                <gol:GoldEventTransactionMessageInput>
                                        <gol:MessageHeader>
                                                <gol:NotificationID>GOLD<xsl:value-of select="concat($NOTIFID, 'DEACT')"/>
                                                </gol:NotificationID>

                                                <gol:GoldNodeType/>
                                                <gol:NotificationType>DEACTIVATION</gol:NotificationType>
                                        </gol:MessageHeader>
                                        <gol:MessageBody>
                                                <gol:SubscriberInformation>
                                                        <gol:SubscriberID>
                                                                <xsl:value-of select="$ACID"/>
                                                        </gol:SubscriberID>
                                                        <gol:SubscriberMSISDN>
                                                                <xsl:value-of select="$MSISDN"/>
                                                        </gol:SubscriberMSISDN>
                                                        <gol:SubscriberIMSI>
                                                                <xsl:value-of select="$IMSI"/>
                                                        </gol:SubscriberIMSI>
                                                        <gol:SubscriberLangID>
                                                                <xsl:value-of select="$LANG"/>
                                                        </gol:SubscriberLangID>
                                                </gol:SubscriberInformation>
                                                <gol:StateInformation>
                                                        <gol:FState>ACT/STD</gol:FState>
                                                        <gol:TState>PAS/SUSP</gol:TState>
                                                </gol:StateInformation>
                                        </gol:MessageBody>
                                </gol:GoldEventTransactionMessageInput>
                        </soapenv:Body>
                </soapenv:Envelope>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template name="strip_comma">
                <xsl:param name="level"/>
                <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="contains($level, ',')">
                                <xsl:call-template name="strip_comma">
                                        <xsl:with-param name="level">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($level,',')"/>
                                        </xsl:with-param>
                                </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$level"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XSLT will filter will display only the first request output while the second will not be displayed. 
Current Output is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:gol="http://www.example.org/ws/GOldEventTransaction"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><gol:GoldEventTransactionMessageInput><gol:MessageHeader><gol:NotificationID>GOLDB0GQ95PH07QRDEACT</gol:NotificationID><gol:GoldNodeType/><gol:NotificationType>DEACTIVATION</gol:NotificationType></gol:MessageHeader><gol:MessageBody><gol:SubscriberInformation><gol:SubscriberID>2005637</gol:SubscriberID><gol:SubscriberMSISDN>1234567</gol:SubscriberMSISDN><gol:SubscriberIMSI>425062260312424</gol:SubscriberIMSI><gol:SubscriberLangID>ARA</gol:SubscriberLangID></gol:SubscriberInformation><gol:StateInformation><gol:FState>ACT/STD</gol:FState><gol:TState>PAS/SUSP</gol:TState></gol:StateInformation></gol:MessageBody></gol:GoldEventTransactionMessageInput></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

while what I want to achieve is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:gol="http://www.example.org/ws/GOldEventTransaction"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><gol:GoldEventTransactionMessageInput><gol:MessageHeader><gol:NotificationID>GOLDB0GQ95PH07QRDEACT</gol:NotificationID><gol:GoldNodeType/><gol:NotificationType>DEACTIVATION</gol:NotificationType></gol:MessageHeader><gol:MessageBody><gol:SubscriberInformation><gol:SubscriberID>2005637</gol:SubscriberID><gol:SubscriberMSISDN>1234567</gol:SubscriberMSISDN><gol:SubscriberIMSI>425062260312424</gol:SubscriberIMSI><gol:SubscriberLangID>ARA</gol:SubscriberLangID></gol:SubscriberInformation><gol:StateInformation><gol:FState>ACT/STD</gol:FState><gol:TState>PAS/SUSP</gol:TState></gol:StateInformation></gol:MessageBody></gol:GoldEventTransactionMessageInput></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:gol="http://www.example.org/ws/GOldEventTransaction"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><gol:GoldEventTransactionMessageInput><gol:MessageHeader><gol:NotificationID>GOLDB0GQ95PH07QRDEACT</gol:NotificationID><gol:GoldNodeType/><gol:NotificationType>DEACTIVATION</gol:NotificationType></gol:MessageHeader><gol:MessageBody><gol:SubscriberInformation><gol:SubscriberID>3615734</gol:SubscriberID><gol:SubscriberMSISDN>768681826</gol:SubscriberMSISDN><gol:SubscriberIMSI>425062250251886</gol:SubscriberIMSI><gol:SubscriberLangID>ARA</gol:SubscriberLangID></gol:SubscriberInformation><gol:StateInformation><gol:FState>ACT/STD</gol:FState><gol:TState>PAS/SUSP</gol:TState></gol:StateInformation></gol:MessageBody></gol:GoldEventTransactionMessageInput></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

That is to cycle every single request and applying the same check is doing it now

Please help !!!

Answer (score 1):

> I want a XSLT expression that will cycle all the requests, check that
>   Status is 5 and return an output with every different account ID as in
>   the input.

You didn't say what form the output should take. Here's an example of returning each id as an element in an XML document:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <result>
        <xsl:for-each select="notification/data/admin/input/request_set/request/update/account_data[@Status='5']">
            <id>
                <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
            </id>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your (original) example input:

**XML**

```
<notification>
   <data>
      <admin originator="" event_time="2015-02-28T02:26:42+02:00">
         <input>
            <request_set tx_id="Y2xfMDFfMDE6LWFjODQ2MTQ6Y2E3Mjo1NGVmYjA3NjoxNTE3ODA=#YWM4NDYxNDpjYTcyOjU0ZWZiMDc2OjE1MTc5Ng==" tx_timeout="2015-02-28T00:36:51.824Z" tx_command="start">
               <request report="">
                  <update>
                     <account_data id="2005637" parent="3615732" Status="5" instance="1">
                        <info>
                           <additional languageid="ARA" nwop="WMP" expdat="2015-08-17T00:00:00+02:00" exptyp="Deactivate" status="2" as="ACT/STD" dyn="ch=US,gn=,ct=1,enc=true,tp=TP_STUDENTS"/>
                        </info>
                     </account_data>
                  </update>
               </request>
               <request report="">
                  <update>
                     <account_data id="3615734" parent="3615732" Status="5" instance="1">
                        <info>
                           <additional languageid="ARA" nwop="WMP" status="5" as="PAS/SUSP" dyn="ch=US,gn=,ct=1,enc=true,tp=TP_SHABABE"/>
                        </info>
                     </account_data>
                  </update>
               </request>
            </request_set>
         </input>
      </admin>
   </data>
</notification>
```

the **result** is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
   <id>2005637</id>
   <id>3615734</id>
</result>
```

Comment: Many thks, I got that but my previous post was misleading. I have modified it now with complete correct info

Comment: I still don't see what kind of output you expect to get. In any case, I believe the above answer provides the principle - and the implementation of that principle to your specific situation is your job, not mine.

Comment: I have specified also the output now. I'm already aware about your solution for simple cases, but to cycle multiple request is quite difficult to me.Don't wnat you to do my job but if u could give hints on the more detailed request I'd appreciate.

Comment: so...none available to help ?